# get versionName from within a webview

Tags: php, android, webview

I have a webview and on one of the pages I have an "about the app" page which shows the current version app version. However I fear if I have to change the app at some point in the future the version will become misaligned as I have to update it separately in the php webpage.

Is there some code I could use to get the android:versionName as a variable and output the variable (preferably php but I'm open to using other methods).

I would like it if i could use a simple variable like `if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == "com.klingondragon.fakeappname") {` which I use to check if a browser is being used or if it's coming from the app.

Answer (score 1):

Add a [JavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) that returns the version name.

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new VersionJSInterface(), "version");

public static class VersionJSInterface {
  @JavascriptInterface
  public String getVersionName(){
    return BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
  }
}
```

And then in your webview's content you can access an object called version.

```
<script>
  var versionName = version.getVersionName()
</script>
```

Comment: which bit do i replace with `@string/app_version`

Comment: You don't need a separate string resource. The version name should be a static field in BuildConfig.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can get package using this code:

```
String versionName = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                pkName, 0).versionName;
```